# How would I invert a nested array in ruby?

Tags: ruby, arrays

EDITED QUESTION

I have the following method:

```
def stats_by_day(league)
 league.days_of_league.collect do |day|
  roster_for(league).collect do |celeb|
    celeb.tweets_this_day(day).inject(0) {|sum, n| sum + n.retweet_count + n.favorite_count}
  end
 end
end
```

This gives me:

```
Day1, Day2, Day3  Day1  Day2  Day3
 [345, 647, 567], [344, 222, 675] etc
      TEAM1            TEAM2
```

However  what I want is

```
Team1 Team2 Team3   Team1 Team2 Team3
 [345, 344, 567]     [647, 222, 876]
       DAY1                DAY2
```

I've tried  switching the 2nd and 3rd lines of the method but that didn't work.  Do I have what I need to get my desired output?

OLD QUESTION (for reference)

If I have...

```
[[a1,b1,c1],[a2,b2,c2],[a3,b3,c3]]
```

how would I get...

```
[[a1,a2,a3],[b1,b2,b3],[c1,c2,c3]]
```

Looking for a ruby approach. Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean for the elements `a1`, `b1`,... to be methods or local variables?  If so, your output must contain the values of those methods or variables.  For example, if `a1=1`, `b1=2`, `a2=3`, `b2=4`, where `a=[[a1,b1],[a2,b2]] => [[1,2],[3,4]]`, your desired result be `[[1,3][2,4]]`. If you meant to have `[[:a1, :a2...` or `[['a1', 'a2'...`, please edit both arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the nested arrays are all of the same size you can use the [`Array#transpose`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) method:

```
ary = [[:a1, :b1, :c1],[:a2, :b2, :c2],[:a3, :b3, :c3]]
ary.transpose
# => [[:a1, :a2, :a3], [:b1, :b2, :b3], [:c1, :c2, :c3]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
 a.flatten.group_by { |x| x[/[a-zA-Z]+/] }.values
 => [["a1", "a2", "a3"], ["b1", "b2", "b3"], ["c1", "c2", "c3"]]
```

Comment: Several problems here, I'm afraid.  Firstly, nowhere is it said that the elements of the array are strings or symbols.  (Yes, @toro2k used symbols in his example, but `transpose` doesn't care what the objects are.) Presumably, `a1` is a method or local variable.  Suppose we had `a = [[a1,b1],[a2,b2]]` where `a1 = 1`, `b1 = 2`, `a2 = 3`, `b2 = 4`.  Then `a => [[1, 2], [3, 4]]`, causing your regex to choke.  Even if `a` contained strings or symbols, your code depends on the data.  Suppose, for example, `a = [[:a1,:a2],[:a3,:a4]]`.  Your code incorrectly returns `[:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4]`.

Comment: Thanks for inputs. Yes the example I have given is dependent on the data. I do not think there will be case where a1 will be a method or a variable, because operations happen on data but not on method definitions itself or by variables itself. However, agreed that using strings is not the best bet here.

Comment: One commonly defines array whose elements are the values of variables or methods; e.g., `a = [a1,a2]`, but of course Ruby evaluates those values when creating the array `a`; e.g, `a = [1,2]`.  The values of `a1` and `a2` can be any objects; there is no reason to assume they will be strings rather than hashes, for example.  When you see code that looks like `[a1,a2]`, what can `a1` and `a2` be other than methods or local variables?  If the array were instead defined with literals, you'd see something like `[1,:a,'b']`.